# C++ how to use a pointer to circular shift array element

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, rotation, shift

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void RotateLeft(unsigned char* in)
{
    unsigned int* q= (unsigned int*)in;
    *q = (*q >> 8)|((*q & 0xff) << 24);
}
int main() {
    unsigned char temp[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    RotateLeft(temp);
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        cout<<temp[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

the output is: b c d a.

Could you explain how does this line work:

```
*q = (*q >> 8)|((*q & 0xff) << 24);
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How can this work ?

The pointer `in` to the array looks like:

```
         +---+---+---+---+
in -->   | a | b | c | d | 
         +---+---+---+---+
```

Let's assuming that each char would be coded as a sequence of 8 bits (ok, language-lawyers would argue that a byte is not necessarily 8 bits, but in practice, it's quite often the case).  So in binary it would look like:

```
         +----------+----------+----------+----------+
in -->   | 01100001 | 01100010 | 01100011 | 01100100 | 
         +----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Let's assume that the int is made of 32 bits.  The ugly [casting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)#Typed_pointers_and_casting) trick with unsigned `int* q= (unsigned int*)in;` is to instruct the compiler to handle the pointer as if it would point to an `int`, combining several char in a single value:

```
         +----------+----------+----------+----------+
q  -->   | 01100001   01100010   01100011   01100100 | 
         +----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Attention:  for the sake of simplicity, I'll assume here a big endian CPU architecture. But I'll come back later on this by explaining how it works with little endian.
This binary coded number in the example represents 1633837924 in decimal notation.

If you now perform  `(*q >> 8)` it will [shift the bits](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/bitshift.html) of this integer to the right by 8 bits, injecting 0 bits on the left:

```
         +----------+----------+----------+----------+
*q >>8 = | 00000000   01100001   01100010   01100011 | 
         +----------+----------+----------+----------+
                        'a'         'b'        'c'
```

Now `0xff` in binary in `11111111`. If you now perform the following [bitwise and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation `(*q & 0xff)` you will set all the bits to 0, except the last 8 bits:

```
            +----------+----------+----------+----------+
(*q&0xff) = | 00000000   00000000   00000000   01100100 | 
            +----------+----------+----------+----------+
                                                 'd'
```

if you combine this with `...<<24`, you shift all the bits to the left by 24 positions, by injecting 0 to the right:

```
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+
(*q&0xff)<<24 = | 01100100   00000000   00000000   00000000 | 
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+
                     'd'
```

If you now combine these two terms with a [bitwise or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR), you'll obtain:

```
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+
*q >>8 =        | 00000000   01100001   01100010   01100011 | 
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+
                             'a'         'b'        'c'
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+
(*q&0xff)<<24 = | 01100100   00000000   00000000   00000000 | 
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+
                     'd'
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+
| (bitwise or)  | 01100100   01100001   01100010   01100011 | 
                +----------+----------+----------+----------+
                     'd'        'a'         'b'        'c'
```

So in this case it rotates right.  This is the consequence of the big-endian assumption that I made.

### But is this safe ?

The problem with this code is that it assumes a lot of things which are not guaranteed by standard C++. So it is not guaranteed to work.   It works only if:

- a `char` is 8 bits long (because the shift right and shift left are multiples of 8).
- an `int` is 32 bits long (because it assumes that the combination of shifts corresponds to exactly 32 bits).
- the direction of the rotation depends on endianness.  Only little endian ensures a rotation to the left.

Here the impact on [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness):

- In my step by step explanations, I've used big-endian, where the bytes are taken sequentially in the right order to form the integer.  THe rotation is done towards the right.
- If you have a little endian architecture, which is much more probable, the bytes would be loaded into the register as an integer in the reverse order (e.g. `a b c d` in memory order would be loaded as `d c b a` for the calculations) , the bytes would then be shifted and combined as explained to the right (e.g. `a d c b`), but when stored back into memory, the bytes would again be reversed (e.g. `b c d a`), so the rotate right that is done on the integer results in a rotate left if looking at the individual chars.

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed explanation. It’s very clear! Just one more question on the ‘(*q >> 8) | ((*q & 0xff) << 24)’: when the program does these two operation, why, when implementing ‘ ((*q & 0xff) << 24)’ would the original left 24 bits are still there for  ‘(*q >> 8)‘ to operate on?

Comment: @Jason because these shift operations are performed on the value of *q and do not change the original content of the object unless there's an assignment. It's like writing a+15; you wouldn't expect a to change either.

Answer (score 3):

It's just deferencing the pointer, which returns an `int`, and performing all the bit operations on that. It's effectively the same as:

```
unsigned int val = *q;
val = (val >> 8)|((val & 0xff) << 24);
*q = val;
```

The program itself has undefined behavior. You can't access a `char` array through an `unsigned int*` pointer. It also assumes that `sizeof (unsigned int)` is `4`, the array has no padding between elements, and a particular endianness of the CPU.